# Where did my persistence go?

Tags: partition, kali-linux, persistence

I've had a Kali Linux bootable usb for a long time now. Last night I updated Kali, and shutdown when I went to bed.

I boot up now, and it appears everything is wiped. All files gone. The desktop environment is exactly the same if you had installed Kali for  the very first time.

I think that somehow everything was wiped. However, I open gparted, and see that my persistence partition is still on the usb. 50%of the usb used, which was the correct amount before I began the updates.

I believe my files and user are still on the usb, but how would I access them so when I click on the persistence option, it goes back to how it has been prior to the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see the persistance partition on the USB drive and you know its name, simply mount it using the `mount` command. If `mount` reports an error, it can usually be fixed with `fsck`, file system check utility.

```
mount /dev/[device/partition name] /mnt [or wherever]
```

You may then copy files off of /mnt

Then, maybe check and edit /etc/fstab

Look for changes that could make it not remount persistence at boot.